# jquery - checking for inline javascript on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to test if a custom attribute is a function?  I've tried using jquery's isFunction method, but it doesn't seem to work with this scenario.

For example:

```
<input id="test" class='date' oncomplete="function() { alert('i am a function'); }" type="text" />

<script>
    $(".date").livequery(function () {
        var onComplete = $(this).attr("oncomplete");
        if ($.isFunction(onComplete)) {
            $(this).mask("99/99/9999", { completed: onComplete });
        } else {
            $(this).mask("99/99/9999");
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have several date fields.  I'm trying to give a couple of them special behavior.  I know I can just have a separate jquery selector to set them up with the behavior they need.  But wanted to see if there was an inline way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting attributes from DOM elements, jQuery converts them to functions if they are DOM events (like `onclick`, `onkeyup`, etc.), but not if they are custom "events" (example: http://jsfiddle.net/FJWhp/1/).

I suggest NOT doing it this way.  I suggest putting the function in your JavaScript, and use a `data-` attribute to store its name.

Like this:

```
<input id="test" class='date' data-complete="dateComplete" type="text" />

<script>
    function dateComplete() {
      alert('i am a function'); 
    }

    $(".date").livequery(function () {
        var onComplete = $(this).data("complete");
        if ($.isFunction(window[onComplete])) {
            $(this).mask("99/99/9999", { completed: window[onComplete] });
        } else {
            $(this).mask("99/99/9999");
        }
</script>
```

Or better yet, just have the function in JavaScript and don't attach it to the DOM element at all.

```
<input id="test" class='date' type="text" />

<script>
    $(".date").livequery(function () {
        $(this).mask("99/99/9999", {
            completed: function(){
              alert('i am a function');
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: in your second example, how would jquery get the "complete" data if it isn't attached to the DOM element?

Comment: @Brosto: I edited the answer, that was a copy&paste fail.  In the 2nd example there is no data on the DOM element, and the function is anonymous.  In the function, you can decide what to do.

Comment: having trouble getting your first example working.  can you take a look?  http://jsfiddle.net/VBGhs/

Comment: @Brosto: The problem is jsFiddle wraps your code in a `ready` function.  Therefore `dateComplete` is not global (part of `window`).  You can change it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/VBGhs/1/, or you can make an object to hold the functions, and use that: http://jsfiddle.net/VBGhs/2/.

Comment: Ahh, i think I was working off an example you had edited.  I was missing the window[] on $.isFunction(window[onComplete])...  That worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use `eval()` for this; inline JS in an attribute is just a plain string.

I'd highly suggest you to not use inline JS at all - it's not nice to read and even harder to maintain/debug.